# MyDate may not respond to setDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an object calander as

```
 MyDate * calander = [[MyDate alloc] init];
```

in `MyDate` I have:

```
-(void) setDate:(NSDate *) NewDate  {
    self.aDate = NewDate;
.
.
.
}
```

the statement: `[calander setDate:mdr.cDate];`  issues a warning "MyDate may not respond to setDate."

Comment: Well, does MyDate respond to setDate? You neglected to include its source code.

Comment: I included relevant partial source code of MyDate as follows:-(void) setDate:(NSDate *) NewDate  {
    self.aDate = NewDate;
.
.
.
}

Comment: @saman01 It's probably because you didn't declare the method in the `.h` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the `MyDate.h` header file in the class that is trying to call `setDate:`? Usually when I bump into this error it's because I forgot an `#include`.

Comment: Thanksfor reply. MyDate.h is included.

Answer (score 1):

@Nate [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765068/mydate-may-not-respond-to-setdate/6765112#6765112) if you incuded `MyDate.h`, to which you answered yes.

His question also had an implicit  . . .

Does `MyDate.h` contain either

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *myDate;
```

or

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date;
```

otherwise including it will do nothing!

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten a declaration.